# Cart in database, PHP + MySQL

Tags: database, session, shopping-cart

I have an e-shop with cart in session, but customer wants also data in database. Written in PHP and MySQL, but it's not so important.

Advantages:

1. If user is logged in on other pc or tablet, we can load them his cart from database.
2. We saw what users have in their carts.

Problems:

- I don't know if there will be better to save all user carts to database, included not logged users (with PHP_SESSION_ID) or just only for logged users
- if I save only for logged users, informations will be duplicated in sessions and database, so I must synchronize them also when user is already logged in on another pc, I must check with every request, if data wasn't changed in database.
- if I save only to database with PHP_SESSION_ID (and user_id if user is logged) then the problem is, that user can have something in cart on pc1 and something on pc2 - so what's the best way - merge these items?

Thank you for your opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use only database solution because data won't be redundant.

I am saving PHP_SESSION_ID and user_id if user is logged, so if some customer is logged in on multiple devices, web shows him his sync shopping cart.